# Thread blocking UI in android

Tags: android, multithreading, bluetooth

I am using this sample code from the Android Bluetooth guide, found here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html under "Connecting as a Client".

```
private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
    // Use a temporary object that is later assigned to mmSocket,
    // because mmSocket is final
    BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
    mmDevice = device;

    // Get a BluetoothSocket to connect with the given BluetoothDevice
    try {
        // MY_UUID is the app's UUID string, also used by the server code
        tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
    } catch (IOException e) { }
    mmSocket = tmp;
}

public void run() {
    // Cancel discovery because it will slow down the connection
    mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

    try {
        // Connect the device through the socket. This will block
        // until it succeeds or throws an exception
        mmSocket.connect();
    } catch (IOException connectException) {
        // Unable to connect; close the socket and get out
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException closeException) { }
        return;
    }

    // Do work to manage the connection (in a separate thread)
    manageConnectedSocket(mmSocket);
}

/** Will cancel an in-progress connection, and close the socket */
public void cancel() {
    try {
        mmSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) { }
}
```

}

In my onCreate, I call

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    connectionManager= new ConnectionManager(this);
    connectionManager.start();
```

The connectionManager launches a ConnectThread and the connect thread successfully connects to another bluetooth device. However, the layout isn't rendered until the ConnectThread returns (exactly, when mmSocket.connect() stops blocking). 
How can I get the layout to display first?

Comment: What does ConnectionManager.start() look like?  If it's calling ConnectThread.run() directly, it will block the UI thread.  You'd want to call ConnectThread.start() instead.

Answer (score 1):

In stead of creating the connection manager from the UI Thread, why dont you create it in a worker thread as follows:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
               connectionManager= new ConnectionManager(YourActivity.this);
               connectionManager.start();
            }
        }).start();
```

This way you never get to block the UI Thread, hope this helps...

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap it in an async task
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 0):

Remember, `setContentView()` only takes action once the `onCreate()` method returns. Taking this into account, you should run the code in another thread and not in the UI thread.

Your code should look something like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
               connectionManager= new ConnectionManager(this);
               connectionManager.start();
            }
    }).start();
}
```